# Discriminant of $x^n+a$

Tags: polynomials, discriminant

The polynomial [discriminant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of $x^2+c$ is $-4c$.

The discriminant of $x^3+q$ is $-27q^2.$

Is it true then the discriminant of $x^n+a$ is $-n^na^{n-1}$?

Comment: $(-1)^{\color{red}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}n^n a^{n-1}$

Comment: @achillehui Why?

Comment: Let $z_i$ be the roots, the discriminant is defined as $$\prod\limits_{1\le i < j \le n}(z_i - z_j)^2 = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\prod\limits_{i \ne j}(z_i - z_j)$$ The strange sign factor comes from the need to flip $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pair of $i,j$ to get the definition to 2nd form.